# Static Nginx with Modsecurity

Tags: c, docker, nginx, gcc, mod-security

Trying to add Modsecurity v3.0.4 in to Nginx v1.19.9 but running in to some errors I do not understand. There are MANY errors similar to the ones I pasted below but did not include them all. My intention is to create a static Nginx binary and not use the dynamic Modsecurity module.  Thanks for any help.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest as build

#Define build argument for version
ARG NGNX_VERSION=1.19.8
ARG PCRE_VERSION=8.44
ARG OSSL_VERSION=1.1.1k
ARG ZLIB_VERSION=1.2.11
ARG GEO_DB_RELEASE=2021-04
ARG MODSEC_BRANCH=v3.0.4
ARG OWASP_BRANCH=v3.3/master

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN echo "Installing Dependencies" && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual general-dependencies  \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    byacc \
    build-base                                                          \
    gnupg                                                               \
    perl                                                                \
    linux-headers                                                       \
    pcre-dev                                                            \
    wget                                                                \
    geoip-dev \
    curl-dev \
    flex \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    geoip-dev \
    git \
    libc-dev \
    libmaxminddb-dev \
    libstdc++ \
    libtool \
    libxml2-dev \
    linux-headers \
    lmdb-dev \
    make \
    openssl-dev \
    pcre-dev \
    yajl-dev \
    zlib-dev

# Clone and compile modsecurity. Binary will be located in /usr/local/modsecurity
RUN echo "Installing ModSec Library" && \
    git clone -b ${MODSEC_BRANCH} --depth 1 https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity && \
    git -C /tmp/ModSecurity submodule update --init --recursive && \
    (cd "/tmp/ModSecurity" && \
        ./build.sh && \
        ./configure --with-lmdb  && \
        make -j 10 && \
        make install \
    )

# Retrieve required packages
RUN echo 'Cloning Modsec Nginx Connector, GeoIP, ModSec OWASP Rules, and download/extract nginx and GeoIP databases' && \
    git clone -b master --depth 1 https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx.git && \
    git clone -b ${OWASP_BRANCH} --depth 1 https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset.git /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs && \
    wget -q https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OSSL_VERSION.tar.gz     && \
    tar -xzf openssl-$OSSL_VERSION.tar.gz                                   && \
    wget -q https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-$PCRE_VERSION.tar.bz2        && \
    tar -xjf pcre-$PCRE_VERSION.tar.bz2                                     && \
    wget -q http://zlib.net/zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION.tar.gz                       && \
    tar -xzf zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION.tar.gz                                      && \
    wget -q http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGNX_VERSION.tar.gz            && \
    tar -xzf nginx-$NGNX_VERSION.tar.gz


# Install Nginx with PCRE, OpenSSL, Geomod, Zlib
RUN set -x                                                                  && \
    cd /tmp/nginx-$NGNX_VERSION                                             && \
    ./configure                                                             \
    --with-compat                               \
        --with-ld-opt="-static"                                             \
        --with-pcre=/tmp/pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}                               \
        --with-zlib=/tmp/zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}                               \
        --with-openssl=/tmp/openssl-${OSSL_VERSION}                         \
        --with-http_realip_module                                           \
        --with-http_v2_module                                               \
    --add-module=/tmp/ModSecurity-nginx                 \
        --with-http_ssl_module                                              && \
    make -j 10                                                              && \
    make install                                                            && \
    strip /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx                                       && \
    apk del general-dependencies

# Symlink access and error logs to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr, in
# order to make use of Docker's logging mechanism
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log                     && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log

RUN addgroup -S nginx && adduser -S -G nginx nginx
```

**Failures occur during the Nginx make section. There are many similar to these.**

```
/usr/include/c++/10.2.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:225: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char const*, char const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/10.2.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:219: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/10.2.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:212: undefined reference to `std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/libmodsecurity.a(lt5-libmodsecurity_la-rule.o): in function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_rule.cc':
/usr/include/c++/10.2.1/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/libmodsecurity.a(lt5-libmodsecurity_la-rule.o): in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/c++/10.2.1/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/libmodsecurity.a(lt5-libmodsecurity_la-rule.o): in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/tmp/ModSecurity/src/variables/rule.cc:23: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/Makefile:267: objs/nginx] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you tried successfully outside of the container build first?
Alpine is a very reduced distro. So you have to be sure all dependencies are present in expected versions. So sounds like debugging of dependencies to me without further details.

Comment: @aholbreich I have not tried that specifically but I have tried to do the build using ubuntu and debian base images. Unfortunately those gave me the same result. I will try totally outside of the container though, good idea. Will let you know, thanks.

Comment: Okay it looks like it's tied to me wanted to statically compile. I was able to build nginx with modsecurity without the --ld-opt="static" but if I add them I get all my errors. Unfortunately my entire plan hinges on being able to statically compile.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  It looks similar to [this](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx/issues/101) question, which also is not terribly resolved

Comment: Unfortunately no I did not resolve this. I haven't gotten back to trying in a while. I will check out your link.

Answer (score 0):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set project here.

I've never attempted a static compile, but I suggest you ask the question on the modsecurity mailinglist or on the specific modsecurity developer mailinglist.

https://sourceforge.net/p/mod-security/mailman/